# How to create a table in javascript and hold in memory for use on another page within a web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html files which are the two pages in my application

Page 1 = `Home.html`

Page 2 = `Stats.html`

When Page 1 is loaded, I am making `AJAX` calls to the Facebook API which returns some data and then I want to build a table using that data.

I then want to keep the table in memory and append it to a div on Page 2 when the user navigates to Page 2.

In this way, the wait time for the user is drastically reduced because in the time it takes them to navigate from Page 1 to Page 2, the majority of the work by the browser has been done.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You might want to create the table using javascript on the existing page rather than navigating to the next? You should learn more about how javascript webapps work.

Comment: Embed the page 2 in page 1, keep it hidden until the data is loaded and then display it. Oh and learn HTML.

Comment: Sorry people are so rude.  It sucks to be a newb, you'll get there eventually.

Comment: I fail to see how it was rude? Both comments provided answers explaining how to solve a common problem.

Comment: I suppose you could use something like `localStorage` (since you are using JavaScript already) - see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp - Keep in mind, though, what would happen if users go to page 2 first (and the table/data has not been set yet) - you would probably need to handle this use case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stats.html` page should look into cached data which is fetched from `Home.html`. This is technically **perfectly possible**.

Before I give some details, ensure that the code that fecthes data from Facebook API is the same used between your two pages. The idea is to create a function that:

1. Looks for cached table data and retrieve it if found
2. If not found, fetch data from Facebook API and store it in the cache
3. Return the table data

Remember clearing or overriding the cache time to time.

In order to properly store data, there are two main ways:

1. **Cookies**

This is the traditional way to store data across a website. These are sent to your server at each request, which is not actually necessary but still helps you client-side. Cookies are controversial because subjects to many security flaws, so I wouldn't recommend using them.

2. **Local storage**

This is more modern in browsers, but less compatible with old browsers. This allows you to store data across a web site. This method is getting more and more common, I think you should use this. On top of that, I recommend using an helper library in order to ease the storage, like [store](https://github.com/nbubna/store).

More info about web storage at [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage).